# Access Wifi in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, api, wifi, adhoc, ssid

Is there an API or another way to get the SSID of the currently connected Wifi, create a new ad-hoc network, etc? All help is great! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Great minds think alike...

Comment: Give us a bone as to what you have already looked at?  What properties have you reviewed so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into [Managed Wifi](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) or [Native Wifi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705969.aspx). Managed wifi uses the native wifi api itself.